# "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value" when reading and parsing JSON file in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I am trying to read and parse a JSON file in PowerShell and I cannot seem convert a specific array. It works fine with other arrays and I am close to banging my head on the desk.

Here is a very simplified version of what I have. Note that I use exactly the same logic in other places and it works just fine:

Powershell script:

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic

class Group{
    [string]$name
}

$json = Get-Content -Raw -Path .\config.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$groups = [List[Group]]$json.groups
Write-Output $json
```

JSON file:

```
{
    "groups":[
        {
            "name": "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anybody please tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the direct conversion from `[object[]]` to `[List[Group]]` that fails in this statement:

```
[List[Group]]$json.groups
```

You can solve this with an intermediate conversion from `[object[]]` to `[Group[]]` - PowerShell will gladly handle this conversion natively - after which the array satisfies the parameter constraints of one of the `List` constructors, since `[Group[]]` implements `[IEnumerable[Group]]`:

```
[List[Group]]::new([Group[]]$json.groups)
```

Comment: Ok this worked. But why is it that other arrays work just fine using the exact same logic? I have a users array which contains name and password and Powershell manages to parse this just fine. I don't do anything differently, only the class name and the properties are different.

Comment: @LeonidasFett Update [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73647842/edit) with the example you're describing if you want me to explain why it doesn't fail in the same way :)

Comment: That's weird, I swear it used to work before with the users array. Now, when I execute my script with the users array, I get the same error. This is giving me a headache. XD

Comment: Even works without `new()`, using only cast syntax: `[List[Group]] [Group[]] $json.groups`

Comment: It does indeed, although PowerShell ends up doing the exact same thing :)